# can I use MongoDb in server-less mode?

Tags: mongodb

I'm considering using MongoDb for a backing store for a WPF app that I'm building. Mostly just to get some exposure to NoSQL. Ideally I'd like to make a mongodb database, put it in my application's root folder (or ./data) and connect to it with LINQ -- without having mongo.exe running. I did something similar recently with SQLite and found it to be a great change from XML for data storage.

Is this possible with MongoDb? All the samples that I've seen require mongod.exe to be running when you connect to the database. And the data is always stored in c:\data\db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer, yes. Need to use the --dbpath switch and [version 1.5.2](http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1154) (for "upsert").

Comment: Can you please be more elaborate on that?

Comment: @tunnuz: sorry, so long ago that I don't recall exactly what I was doing... Perhaps start mongo.exe with the --dbpath switch when your app starts?